# Create a new pandas dataframe from a python list of lists with a column with lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python list of lists, e.g. `[["chunky","bacon","foxes"],["dr_cham"],["organ","instructor"],...]` and would like to create a pandas dataframe with one column containing the lists:

```
 0 ["chunky","bacon","foxes"] 
 1 ["dr_cham"] 
 2 ["organ","instructor"] .
 . .
```

The std constructor (l is the list here)

```
pd.DataFrame(l)
```

returns a dataframe with 3 columns in that case.

How would this work? I'm sure it's very simple, but I'm searching for a solution since a while and can't figure it out for some obscure reason.

Thanks,
B.

Comment: In connection with the name of your list, you might wanna read [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should achieve what you want:

```
import pandas as pd

l = [["hello", "goodbye"], ["cat", "dog"]]

# Replace "lists" with whatever you want to name the column
df = pd.DataFrame({"lists": l})
```

After printing `df`, we get

```
              lists
0  [hello, goodbye]
1        [cat, dog]
```

Hope this helps -- let me know if I can clarify anything!

Comment: I agree, using a dictionary is the best approach.

Comment: thanks a million, that was exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Happy to help @user3379621!

Comment: How do I create a Pandas df where all the elements of the lists are in separate columns as well? @PeterDolan For example from the OP's original question itself, I'd want `hello` in column  1 and `goodbye` in column 2. For the second row, `cat` in column 1, and `dog` in column 2

Comment: @Abhishek hmm, I need a bit more information. Will all lists be the same length? what do you want the columns titled? It probably makes sense to ask this as a new question -- feel free to ping me if you do that and I'll look into it

Comment: I did, @Peter Dolan and I have got a satisfactory answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This pattern is rarely if ever a good idea and defeats the purpose of Pandas, but if you have some unusual use case that requires it, you can achieve it by further nesting your inner lists an additional level in your main list, then creating a DataFrame from that:

```
l = [[x] for x in l]
df = pd.DataFrame(l)

                        0
0  [chunky, bacon, foxes]
1               [dr_cham]
2     [organ, instructor]
```

Comment: I know, but it's a very specific problem.